# Connecting to Azure SQL Database through Azure Data Factory: assigning a static IP to integration runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory copy activity that will copy some table data from a CSV file to an Azure SQL Database. I'm having trouble getting Data Factory to connect with Azure SQL DB, and I don't want to turn on "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" since I don't want some services to access the Azure SQL server.

I've tried setting up firewall IP rules to allow access to only the IP Data Factory uses, but I've discovered that it uses a different IP every time it tries to connect to my Azure SQL DB. I've also tried searching for a list of ranges that Data Factory pulls from to add to the firewall rules, but there doesn't seem to be such a list anywhere.

Is there any work around for this? Or is there any way to assign a static IP to Data Factory or it's integration runtime so I can just assign that IP to a firewall rule?

Comment: Where is the csv?  Azure SQL DB can upload directly from blob store for example, using BULK INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, data factory now support static IP address range now. We can add these IP to the firewall to allow the access to the server.

With the [introduction of Static IP address range](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses), you can now whitelist IP ranges for the particular Azure integration runtime region to ensure you don’t have to allow all Azure IP addresses in your cloud data stores. This way, you can restrict the IP addresses that are permitted to access the data stores.

[image]

For more details, please ref this Azure official document:

1. [Azure Data Factory now supports Static IP address ranges](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/azure-data-factory-now-supports-static-ip-address-ranges/ba-p/1117508)
2. [service tags IP range download link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#discover-service-tags-by-using-downloadable-json-files)

Feedback: [Static IP ranges for Data Factory and add ADF to list of Trusted Azure Services](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/20565967-static-ip-ranges-for-data-factory-and-add-adf-to-l)

For example, bellow is the my Data factory AustraliaEast static IP range:
[image]

But the static IP lists are updated and published weekly.

Hope this helps.